# PHP - Yii 2.0 Multiple images are save in folder but not saved in database

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I have used `use kartik\file\FileInput;` (extension) for saving multiple images from single form submit.
The images are save locally but are not saving in the database.

## Here is my Model Code media.php

```
namespace app\models;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
class Media extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
        public function rules(){
        return [
            [['title'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => ['gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'PNG', 'GIF'], 'checkExtensionByMimeType' =>  false ,'maxFiles' => 4, 'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 1024],
                        [['extension'], 'string', 'max' => 6],
                ];        
        }
```

## Controller code:

```
if ($mediamodel->load ( Yii::$app->request->post () )) {
    $title = UploadedFile::getInstances ( $mediamodel, 'title' );
    foreach ($title as $key => $file)          {
        $file->saveAs(Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/images/hotel/'. $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);}
        foreach ($title as $key => $file){   
        echo $mediamodel->title."*********";
        $mediamodel->title = $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
        echo " \Title: ".$mediamodel->title;
        $mediamodel->save ();
    }
}
```

## My view code:

```
use kartik\file\FileInput; 
$form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'layout' => 'horizontal', {label}\n{beginWrapper}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}\n{endWrapper}", 
    'fieldConfig' => ['horizontalCssClasses' => ['label' => 'col-md-3','offset' => 'col-md-offset-2','wrapper' => 'col-md-4', 'error' => '','hint' => '',],],'
    options' => [ 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', ], ]);?>

<?php echo $form->field($mediamodel, 'title[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), ['options'=>['multiple' => true]]); 
Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Add' : 'Update');
```

Comment: Check the log in the debug bar after "Model not inserted due to validation error." or any other hints on what might be wrong. And please update the question with the view code, instead of in a comment.

Comment: Check for the Errors first i.e `$mediamodel->getErrors()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$mediamodel->save (false);
```

instead of

```
$mediamodel->save ();
```

Answer (score 1):

// You should handle errors like this.

```
if(!$mediamodel->save()){
    // handle the errors of model.
    var_dump($mediamodel->getErrors());
}
```

Comment: why is error is given I don't understand
array(1) { ["title"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Please upload a file." } }